# composer installs dev version of package when using 0 for patch version with caret

Tags: composer-php

In my composer file I have

`"drupal/core": "^9.1.0",`

When install using composer update --no-dev

It installs 9.1.0-alpha1 rather that what I would expect, i.e. the latest version 9.1.7 at the time of writing.

When specifying  `drupal/core": "^9.1.1",` it installs the latest version as I would expect.

In other words changing the patch version from 1 to 0 seems to affect if composer installs 9.1.0-alpha1 or 9.1.7.

For completeness I am also specifying    `"minimum-stability": "dev", "prefer-stable": true,`

Running composer why-not/prohibits I get the following:

```
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
drupal/core                     9.1.7       requires          composer/semver (^3.0)                    
drupal-composer/drupal-project  dev-master  does not require  composer/semver (but 1.7.2 is installed)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Please share more details - could another package require that version of `drupal/core`?

Comment: seems unlikely as that would prevent me installing 9.1.7 as well?

Comment: What does `composer why-not drupal/core 9.1.7`  yield in the first case?